# why is mapping over my array items causing a glitch on page load and refresh in React?

Tags: reactjs, mapping

IN React, i am mapping over the items in my array, then rendering the images/content in  but on page load, refrsh, and onClick, there is a flash or glitch that renders parts of the next array item.

```
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(2);

  const loadMore = () => {
    setVisible((prevValue) => prevValue + 1);
  };
```

///I think it can be due to mapping over the array before it's initialized somewhere where visible is set but i'm not sure how to fix it.

```
  {blogs && blogs.length > 0 && blogs.slice(0, visible).map((blog, index) => (
    <Thumbnails key={index} blog={blog} index={index} />
  ))}
  <LoadMore>
    {blogs && visible <= blogs.length - 1 && (
      <Button onClick={loadMore}>
        <ButtonText>Load more</ButtonText>
      </Button>
    )}
```